# FIltering objects by year in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Recently, I sorted array of objects by dates in ascending order and not including empty strings/undefined. I am having trouble creating a filter that will filter this array from a specific year to another.

For example: I have an array called:

```
var activities = [
  { "title": 'Hiking', "date": '06/28/2012' },
  { "title": 'Shopping', "date": '01/18/2013' },
  { "title": 'Trekking', "date": '02/21/2013' },
  { "title": 'Sleeping', "date": '11/28/2013' },
  { "title": 'Driving', "date": ' ' },
  { "title": 'Running', "date": ' ' },
  { "title": 'Eating', "date": '12/31/2013' },
  { "title": 'Cooking', "date": '11/28/2014' },
  { "title": 'Excersise', "date": '02/21/2014' },
  { "title": 'Sking', "date": '04/04/2014' },
  { "title": 'Travelling', "date": '08/28/2018' }
]
```

I want to filter the dates by years 2012-2013. So the result would be:

```
  { "title": 'Hiking', "date": '06/28/2012' }
  { "title": 'Shopping', "date": '01/18/2013' }
  { "title": 'Trekking', "date": '02/21/2013' }
  { "title": 'Sleeping', "date": '11/28/2013' }
  { "title": 'Eating', "date": '12/31/2013' }
```

I made an attempt, but I am stuck on what to do.

```js
var activities = [
  { "title": 'Hiking', "date": '06/28/2012' },
  { "title": 'Shopping', "date": '01/18/2013' },
  { "title": 'Trekking', "date": '02/21/2013' },
  { "title": 'Sleeping', "date": '11/28/2013' },
  { "title": 'Driving', "date": ' ' },
  { "title": 'Running', "date": ' ' },
  { "title": 'Eating', "date": '12/31/2013' },
  { "title": 'Cooking', "date": '11/28/2014' },
  { "title": 'Excersise', "date": '02/21/2014' },
  { "title": 'Sking', "date": '04/04/2014' },
  { "title": 'Travelling', "date": '08/28/2018' }
]

var activitiesData= activities
    .filter(d => d.date&& d.date!== ' ')
    .map(({ title, date }) => ({title, date}))
    .sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date));

console.log(activitiesData)
```

Comment: `.filter(d => d.time&& d.time!== ' ')` you do not have any time - I made you a snippet. Please modify it into a [mcve]

Comment: Yeah I was just about to say the same, `.filter(d => d.time && d.time !== “  “)` will not return any results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the year by slicing ([`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)) the string for getting the last four characters.

```js
var activities = [{ title: 'Hiking', date: '06/28/2012' }, { title: 'Shopping', date: '01/18/2013' }, { title: 'Trekking', date: '02/21/2013' }, { title: 'Sleeping', date: '11/28/2013' }, { title: 'Driving', date: ' ' }, { title: 'Running', date: ' ' }, { title: 'Eating', date: '12/31/2013' }, { title: 'Cooking', date: '11/28/2014' }, { title: 'Excersise', date: '02/21/2014' }, { title: 'Sking', date: '04/04/2014' }, { title: 'Travelling', date: '08/28/2018' }],
    result = activities.filter(({ date }) =>
        2012 <= +date.slice(-4) && +date.slice(-4) <= 2013
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Mind asking why the -4 within the .slice()?

Comment: it takes the last four characters of the string. please have a look  here, too: [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Comment: I get it now, thank you very much. As for the [2012, 2013], is there a way to do per say 2012-2014 or if I have an array containing dates from 20120-2030, and I want to filter dates from 2020-2030 to be the results, do I have to write out the years?

Comment: you could take the values and check against. but you need to convert the value to number.

Answer (score 1):

You can just extract the year using regular expression and make a comparison. I wrote a reusable method for your scenario, hope this helps.

```js
var activities = [
  { "title": 'Hiking', "date": '06/28/2012' },
  { "title": 'Shopping', "date": '01/18/2013' },
  { "title": 'Trekking', "date": '02/21/2013' },
  { "title": 'Sleeping', "date": '11/28/2013' },
  { "title": 'Driving', "date": ' ' },
  { "title": 'Running', "date": ' ' },
  { "title": 'Eating', "date": '12/31/2013' },
  { "title": 'Cooking', "date": '11/28/2014' },
  { "title": 'Excersise', "date": '02/21/2014' },
  { "title": 'Sking', "date": '04/04/2014' },
  { "title": 'Travelling', "date": '08/28/2018' }
]

const getActivitiesByYear = (fromYear, toYear) => activities
  .filter(({
    date
  }) => {
    // get year from date
    let [year] = (date || '').match(/\d{4}/g) || [];
    // convert to number
    year = +year;

    /**
      1. checks if year is valid
      2. if fromYear is not specified returns true, otherwise checks if year is greater than or equal fromYear
      3. if toYear is not specified returns true, otherwise checks if year is less than or equal toYear
    */
    return year && (!fromYear || year >= fromYear) && (!toYear || year <= toYear);
  });

// example
console.log('From: 2012, To: 2013 ==>', getActivitiesByYear(2012, 2013));
console.log('From: 2013 ==>', getActivitiesByYear(2013));
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract the years from the date string with slice. You can then pass as many years in the years array.

```js
var activities = [
  { "title": 'Hiking', "date": '06/28/2012' },
  { "title": 'Shopping', "date": '01/18/2013' },
  { "title": 'Trekking', "date": '02/21/2013' },
  { "title": 'Sleeping', "date": '11/28/2013' },
  { "title": 'Driving', "date": ' ' },
  { "title": 'Running', "date": ' ' },
  { "title": 'Eating', "date": '12/31/2013' },
  { "title": 'Cooking', "date": '11/28/2014' },
  { "title": 'Excersise', "date": '02/21/2014' },
  { "title": 'Sking', "date": '04/04/2014' },
  { "title": 'Travelling', "date": '08/28/2018' }
]


const filterYear =(arr,years)=>{
 const activitiesByYear = arr.filter(({date})=> [...years].includes(date.slice(-4)))
 return activitiesByYear 
}

console.log(filterYear(activities, ['2012','2013']))
```